# Mouse problem with dual monitors on Macbook Pro

Tags: dota-2, macos

I play Dota 2 on my left monitor and whenever I drag my mouse to the far right of the screen, my right monitor picks up on it (I see the cursor on the right screen for <1 seconds) and it lags my game for a fraction of a second.

This doesn't happen with Starcraft 2, so I am confused as to why it happens with Dota. I have tried all the different video settings as well as inputting the command

`dota_mouse_window_lock 1` in the console and launch options, but to no avail.

How can I fix this mouse tracking issue?

Comment: What about other Steam games? Have you tried to play with duo monitors configuration in the OSX itself?

Comment: @klm123 I've tried CSGO and that works fine, but it doesn't really require one to drag their mouse to the edge of a screen. I took a quick glance at the  duo monitor configuration on OSX but I'm not really sure if there were any settings I can tweak to fix the problem.

Comment: You can change monitor's virtual relative placement. But anyway, it doesn't sound like a question, but like a bug for a dota developers to look into.

Comment: Are you in borderless-windowed mode? fullscreen?